# Reference to org.eclipse in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

i am trying to reference:

```
org.eclipse.runtime
```

in my project but through intellisense i can't see it.
Is it an external component? Where can i get there?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you're developing a plugin in Eclipse, you need to add the dependency in your manifest.mf file. Eclipse has lots of [documentation on this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/dependencies.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing an Eclipse plug-in you have to add `org.eclipse.core.runtime` to the plug-in dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF

Open the MANIFEST.MF editor, switch to the 'Dependencies' tab and in the 'Required Plug-ins' section click the 'Add...' button and add `org.eclipse.core.runtime`. Save the file and should now be able to use this.

[image: Example Dependencies]

Note: `org.eclipse.core.runtime` is only usable in a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime
```

To use it in your project add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml if you are using maven or download jar file [1] and add it to your classpath.

[1] http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.7.0/org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.7.0.jar

Comment: Yes sorry i mean org.eclipse.core.runtime
That JAR contains all references that i need or have i to reference anything else?

Comment: You can check pom file for dependencies: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.7.0/org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.7.0.pom. I suggest u to use maven which automatically fetch dependencies.